# Are Database operations thread safe?

Tags: iphone, database, cocoa-touch, sqlite, thread-safety

I am using sqlite in my iPhone app.

I have some database operations, in which I have to insert into two tables different data(means there is no data-dependency). Can I perform these two operations in seperate thread. While the insert operation in each table are more than one. So I am doing this in a while loop also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite itself can be built to be thread-safe (for v3.3.1 or later, if it is compiled with `SQLITE_THREADSAFE` defined). You can verify this by calling `sqlite_threadsafe()`.

I suggest you read the following carefully:

- [SQLite FAQ on threading](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6)

Even if SQLite is thread-safe, you may wish to revisit your design. Having multiple threads write to the database is probably not ideal, and it may be possible to redesign to avoid the requirement altogether.