# iphone - Accessing sqlite3 database from two threads simultaneously

Tags: iphone, sqlite, thread-safety

I'm having two threads running in my iphone application and they will be accessing database.
I'm using the following line of code to open the database and doing insert, select, delete etc (what ever I want).

```
if(sqlite3_open([dataBasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
```

Its working fine. But I am not sure whether accessing database is thread safe or not. Is there any chance of crashing at any instance of time? If both the threads try to access database at the same time, what happens?

Can some one suggest me a good way to access database from two threads simultaneously?

Comment: It's thread-safe (unless you compile it not to be, which is hopefully rare) provided the threads use different database handles. You'll also have to handle SQLITE_BUSY, which can't happen if you have exclusive access to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used google.com and found the following highly relevant link:

[Are Database operations thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796251/are-database-operations-thread-safe)